# Integer.valueOf() invalid int

Tags: java, integer, value-of

I am trying to create color values from r,g,b values adding the alpha byte to create a color int.

But I am getting errors using :

> Integer.valueOf(colorStr,16);

`colorStr` is the string that I build, now the value that sends me error is `"0XFF2f6b55"`
it sends me invalid int.

Comment: Is that too big for int?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is for a signed int.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Eight hex digits, the high bit is set. The maximum for `int` is `0x7FFFFFFF`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Uh... that's what I said. That the OP's string *is too big* for a signed int.

Comment: OK, we're on the same page then. Sorry, my misunderstanding.

Comment: -1 for not posting the exact exception name/message. Please get into the habit of including the *exact* error indicators. (In fact, I bet if you *searched* for said error message ..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's [integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) covers values from -2^31 to 2^31-1 (2147483647). Your value is (4281297749) in decimal which is too big for java's integer.

Java's [long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) covers a much higher range of -2^63 to 2^63-1. Which includes your value, so a suggestion would be to use `Long.valueOf(colorStr, 16)` and switch to using longs. (A suggestion that comes into play when the values that you are working with are outside of the range of integer values).

It seemed to me that you were aware, but in case you were not; the `0x` should be removed if it is part of the string value, as it will give an invalid format exception if left in.

Comment: @Nomin.. Yeah that would work. But OP's `colorStr` contained:  -`0xFF2f6b55`, that's why I said it won't work. `Ox` not needed.

Comment: @RohitJain Ah, well he said the "value" was `0xFF2f6b55`, and since he hinted that other values that he used worked I assumed he knew that the  `0x` is superfluous. I'll edit my answer to reflect the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is too big for a signed int - they go from `-0x80000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`. Try:

```
int i = (int) Long.parseLong(colorStr.substring(2), 16);
```

This will result in a negative `int`, which might not be what you want. (When working with colors, it's probably more convenient to work with a tuple of values for the red, green, blue, and alpha component.)

Neither `valueOf()` or `parseInt()`/`parseLong()` will recognize the `0x` prefix, you need to get rid of it.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's a compiler error. Cannot cast from Long to int.

Comment: No, valueOf does not recognizes `Ox`. We just need to pass the hex code without `Ox`